# How do I shorten the MySQL Connect Time Out - Failover Scenario

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a fail-over scenario in a Wordpress plugin, where a PHP script on my web server tries to connect to a backup database if the production one is offline.

Currently the fallback seems to take up to 60 seconds. Is this the PHP default? How would I set the time out to something like 10 seconds?

Here is the relevant portion of the script...

```
  try
        {
            $DBblue = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$samhost.';'.'dbname='.$DBblue, $samuser, $sampass);
            $DBgreen = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$samhost.';'.'dbname='.$DBgreen, $samuser, $sampass);
        }
        catch (\PDOException $pde)
        {
            // Fallback Database connection
            $althost = get_option('fallback_host');
            $altuser = get_option('fallback_user');
            $altpass = get_option('fallback_password');
            $DBblue = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$althost.';'.'dbname='.$DBblue, $altuser, $altpass);
            $DBgreen = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$althost.';'.'dbname='.$DBgreen, $altuser, $altpass);
        }
```

Comment: perhaps: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout

Comment: My scenario is one where the MySQL server doesn't respond

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$DBblue = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$samhost.';'.'dbname='.$DBblue, $samuser, $sampass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
 $DBgreen = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$samhost.';'.'dbname='.$DBgreen, $samuser, $sampass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "10" ->>> Set timeout to 10 seconds.

PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ->>> Throw exception.

More Information : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: Seems to have broken the fallback connection. There is an example at budgiecollective.com under the text "On Air".

Comment: I had to take the changes down. I checked the syntax of the updated insert and it didn't come up with any errors. can I provide you with any other info to help?